# Node.Js Express app doesn't allow log in when running on AWS ECS behind a Load Balancer

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have a Node.Js app running on an AWS ECS cluster behind a load balancer. It is facing the internet via an Amazon-provided public DNS.

Inside the app there's a user login feature based on passport / express.

When I just launch it as 1 task then it is possible to log in for the user.

When I launch it as more than 1 task, then while it logs in (I can see it in logs) it directly doesn't pass through the other function and logs out.

What could be an issue here?

Comment: Are you using client-side token like JWT or server-side sessions with cookies etc.?

Comment: server-side with the cookies, @slebetman

Comment: Have you ensured that both processes can access the same session storage? Eg. they share the same session folder on disk or they share the same session table in the database etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `sticky session` is not enable and as a result that request distributed randomly across two different tasks and the session does not exist for the user.

**Sticky sessions**

> Sticky sessions are a **mechanism to route requests to the same target** in a target group. This is useful for servers that **maintain state information in order to provide a continuous experience to clients**. To use sticky sessions, the clients must support cookies.

You can enable sticky session in Load load balancer under LB  `attributes`.

[load-balancer-target-groups sticky-sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions)

Comment: That was it! Thank you!